# How to fix MySQL Query Alias unknown column? 2018

Tags: mysql

Server version: 5.6.38 - MySQL Community Server (GPL) 
PHP version: 7.2.1 
PHPMyAdmin: Version information: 4.7.7

This is my mysql query

```
SELECT r.id, r.url, MAX(date) as `max_date`, date
FROM report as r
WHERE max_date = date
GROUP BY id, url
ORDER BY bid DESC;
```

I wanted to retrieve the result of maxdate.

I have already tried `Having` and `Between` it just doesn't work. The alias is unknown column

What I am trying to do is,

I want to retrieve the most recent date of a url.

Example: 
id, url, date 
1, facebook.com, jan 1, 2018  
2, google.com, jan 2, 2018 
3, facebook.com, jan 5, 2018 
4, youtube.com, jan 6, 2018 
5, youtube.com, jan 1, 2018 
6, stackoverflow.com, jan 7, 2018 
7, stackoverflow.com, jan 8, 2018

By running the query it should retrieve,
3, facebook.com, jan 5, 2018
2, google.com, jan 2, 2018
4, youtube.com, jan 6, 2018 
7, stackoverflow.com, jan 8, 2018

Comment: You are generating the alias max_date and using it in same query. Alias is generated as the query runs, so you should not use it in condition with WHERE clause.

Comment: perhaps `WHERE date = Max(date)` ?

Comment: Can you please explain what really are you trying to extract? Because it appears from your query that it will only result in single row (the one with highest date) even if you do not include the WHERE clause. Also 'max_date alias' and 'date' column in resulted row will have same value, since it will be actually same row with highest date. Additionally if it is single row anyway, you do not need to 'order by' and 'group by'.
Moreover, if you are using MAX(date) then why are you using the WHERE clause, because MAX(date) also works like where condition. Please explain what you want so i can help

Comment: @waqashsn check my update example

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 6):

According to [MySQL 5.7 Reference Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/problems-with-alias.html),

> Standard SQL disallows references to column aliases in a WHERE
>   clause

You should not use an alias in WHERE clause since the alias is generated upon running the query and may not be ready when the WHERE condition executes. You get alias is unknown column error because MySQL is not aware of the alias until after it is generated as result of the query. Therefore you can not use alias in WHERE clause here.

(Addition after question edit)

You can get desired result with following query:

```
SELECT r.id, r.url, MAX(date) as `max_date`
FROM report as r
GROUP BY id, url;
```

Query Explanation: In `SELECT` clause you only mention the columns you want to display, the `MAX()` function will already select the maximum values itself (so you do not need a WHERE clause), and the GROUP BY clause tells the result to group all results based on `id` and then `url`.

Comment: I understand it very well now. Okay, let me explain more, in awhile.

Comment: forgot the group by... it retrieved all... but max_date retrieves only the latest date not include the row.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Can you show me what is being returned if you remove the GROUP BY clause.